# On page php or jQuery ajax for pagination?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have site that returns over 14000 results from querying 3 tables that are joined.  At the moment the querying and pagination is being done on the main page and it is starting to run really slowly.

Question is, would using jQuery ajax be quicker than the current method?

Comment: An AJAX implementation would improve loading times (according to what is being returned of course), but not database ones

Comment: I spoke to my host about the speed and they put it down to the query, apparently joining 3 tables is bad?

Comment: Well i always thought JOIN makes things faster in queries, but if you have pretty heavy queries you might want some re-structuring (and also some benchmarking on the times querying a result)

Comment: Sorry, but how is your pagination working if your query return over 14k rows?

Comment: not enough info here on your setup to know what would help the most. can you post an example query?